# Qgis -> DXF2ShapeConverter -> Inscriptions in Qgis

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, dxf

Sorry, but this is my first question which very often was asked . It has not yet answered very well.
I would like to import a DXF with captions in QGIS. I have already tried this with the DXF converter but it always crashed GIS .
Now my question , are there alternatives where I can get the label of the DXF with in the GIS ?
 Mfg Malte